# Repeat many times the same code with R and collect the final results

Tags: r, algorithm, autoregressive-models

i have a problem. I hope that you will understand me. My english is not very good. 
I need to repeat B times (where B is at least one thousand) a R code that i write and collect the 1000 final results. I report the code:

```
phi=0.5
p=1
n=100
M=1000

serie1=arima.sim(model=list(ar =phi ,order=c(p,0,0)),n = n,innov=rnorm(100,0,1))
stima<-arima(serie1,order=c(p,0,0),include.mean=F)
phi.stima=stima$coef

res=stima$residual
ress=res[2:n]
res.c=ress-mean(ress)

serie.b=vector("numeric",length=n+M)

ps=round(runif(1,1,n-1))
serie.b[1]=ps

for(i in (2):(n+M))
     serie.b[i]=phi.stima*serie.b[i-1]+res.c[round(runif(1,1,n-1))]

serie.bb=serie.b[(M+1):(n+M)]

serie.bb=ts(serie.bb)

stima.boot<-arima(serie.bb,order=c(1,0,0),include.mean=F)
phi.stima.boot=stima.boot$coef
phi.res.boot=stima.boot$residual

serie.bb[100]=serie1[100]

previsioni.boot=vector("numeric",length=6)
previsioni.boot[1]=serie1[100]

for(i in (2):(6))
previsioni.boot[i]=phi.stima.boot*previsioni.boot[i-1]

for(i in (2):(100+1000))
     serie.b[i]=phi.stima*serie.b[i-1]+res.c[round(runif(1,1,100))]

future_obs_boot=vector("numeric",length=6)
future_obs_boot[1]=serie1[100]

for(i in (2):(6))
     future_obs_boot[i]=phi.stima*future_obs_boot[i-1]+res.c[round(runif(1,1,100))]


errore.prev.boot=future_obs_boot[6]-previsioni.boot[6]
errore.prev.boot
```

I need to collect B values of "errore.prev.boot". How can i do it.. Please can you help me??
Greetings.
Mario

Comment: Cleanest way would be to put your code in a function and use `replicate()` or `lapply()` or `sapply()` etc. as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

@Shree mentioned a hint to an answer in a comment above. This is one way (I tested on my machine and it works):

```
error.fun <- function(...){
   # put your code here
}

map_dbl(1:1000, error.fun)
```

... sample results ...

```
[1]  0.503403119  0.836490778  1.355713864 -0.020078987  0.417293942 -0.677124914
[7]  1.187536510 -1.802907914  1.479408818 -2.383291163  0.242726786  0.197536877
[13] -0.590292009 -0.104944644 -1.776636919  0.143165564 -0.363264225  1.443686564
```